# PHP 7 delay after uploading a file - Have to wait almost 1 minute to see Result

Tags: wordpress, performance, php-7, opcache, ovh

I'm facing a problem that considerably slow down my development workflow.
I updated my server to PHP 7.2 few days ago, and now, everytime I upload a PHP file, I have to wait 30sec to 1min to see the result.

In php 5.4, the previous version of my server, I hadn't this problem.

My server is an OVH server, I'm in dev mode, I haven't configured any php cache on it.

Do you have any tips ?

Comment: When updating PHP, did you run a DIFF of the two versions' `.ini` files to pull over existing customizations?